# how to print a string array elements in a label ? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

My problem is common which is to print an array elements inside a label in windows form with c# but I wanted to use if statement to print a certain elements not all the elements , the code has two forms :

form 1 :

```
public static String [] names = new String [3];
private void button (sender and whatever ...){

      if(label1.Text.Equals("meal1")){
         names[0] = "name1";
      }
      if(label1.Text.Equals("meal2")){
         names[1] = "name2";
      }
      if(label1.Text.Equals("meal3")){
         names[2] = "name3";
      }
      this.Hide();
      Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
      frm2.Show();
}
```

I did this to send the array data to the next form , the elements of the array are stored depending on user choice from a menu

form 2 :

```
private void Form2_Load(...){

    String [] names2 = {"name1" , "name2" , "name3"};

    for(int i = 0 ; i < Form1.names.Length ; i++){
        if(Form1.names[i].Equals(names2[i])){
             label1.Text = names2[i] + "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

lets say user chooses "meal1" and "meal3" , now when form 2 is loaded I must see "meal1" and "meal3" in the label but all I see is the last choice of the user , I tried `String.join("\n",names2[i]);` but it printed all the array elements I tried `labe1.Text += names2[i] + "\n";` it also prints the last choice for the user.

thank you ...

Comment: You need to use `+=` operator instead of `=` in this line `label1.Text += names2[i] + "\n";`

Comment: printing is, if you send something to a printer.

Comment: Holger , thanks for the info , maybe because am working with java mostly we use the phrase "print" a lot is there an alternative to this phrase ?

Comment: @SalahAkbari , it worked well thank you ,  but null pointer problem appears any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yah, I got your problem. every time you run your code you will get the last name whose condition will be true. Here is solution to your problem.

```
if(Form1.names[i].Equals(names2[i])){
         label1.Text = names2[i] + "\n";
    }
```

In these lines, you are just assigning the name to label1 but every time you assign a new value, the old value is replaced. You should change this assignment line as

```
if(Form1.names[i].Equals(names2[i])){
         label1.Text += names2[i] + "\n";
    }
```

Comment: thank you it worked but another problem appeared which is the null pointer ... is there any null pointer here ?

Comment: Null pointer exception occurs when you overrun loop. Change your for loop as following:
...............................

 for(int i = 0 ; i < .names2.Length ; i++){